# json-schema, json-ld and Schema.org, what's the connection?

Tags: json, schema

I'm understanding that json-ld is json using Scheme.org vocabulary to give context meaning to json objects. Right?
So, in a Person context, givenName will the way to refer to someone's first name.

But I'm failing miserable in understand where json-schema fits in all this schema stuff. 
In fact I would say that the json-schema documentation is missing talk about json-ld and Schema.org, as far as I can tell, at least to let new comers knows it has no connection, if it's the case.

So two question here:

1- Is my understand of json-ld right?

2- What is the connection between json-schema and json-ld/Schema.org?

Comment: I will not answer my own queation because I'm still learning, but I will add my discoveries here for other people with the same questions. 


Json-LD is like I said, a vocabulary to give a json a context.
Json-schema is more like a XSD, it discribes the type, format, restrictions and requiriments for values. 


So if an API uses JSON, it may use both. Json-ld would discribe what "firstName" means and json-schema would discribe the format firstName must comply with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136619/what-are-the-differences-between-json-ld-and-json-schema